# React Native app upload on play store

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make animated scroll on Android, like vertical swipes. But unlike IOS Android scroll-view or flat list does not have support for this future. 
On GitHub, I found appropriate code for my project written by @raymondchooi. 
So I would like to include this code in my project, but it contains corrections in React Native source code.

If I will use this code while uploading on Play Store will it be deleted or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no problem uploading an app with someone else code. As long as you did not copy his app or 'stole' his complete source code without authorization.

Comment: Depending on how you created the app, you will either need to use this link https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps if you created your app with expo
Or https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html